# Pagination: Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$username error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, repository-pattern

The below results in in 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$username' error.

How should this be done? I seem to getting a few errors (Such as protected property & non-object) no matter how many times I look at it?

**AbsractRepository.php**

```
/**
     * Get Results by Page
     *
     * @param int $page
     * @param int $limit
     * @param array $with
     * @return StdClass Object with $items and $totalItems for pagination
     */
    public function getByPage($page = 1, $limit = 10, $with = array())
    {
        $result             = new StdClass;
        $result->page       = $page;
        $result->limit      = $limit;
        $result->totalItems = 0;
        $result->items      = array();

        $query = $this->make($with);

        $model = $query->skip($limit * ($page - 1))
            ->take($limit)
            ->get();

        $result->totalItems = $this->model->count();
        $result->items      = $model->all();

        return $result;
    }
```

**BaseAdminController.php**

```
/**
 * List resources
 *
 * @return void
*/
public function index()
{ 
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $data = $this->model->getByPage($page, 10);
    $objects = Paginator::make($data->items, $data->totalItems, 10);
    $this->layout->content = View::make($this->namespace . '::admin.index')
        ->with('objects', compact('objects'));
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($objects as $user)
<tr class="">
    <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td class="center">Super Administrator</td>
    <td class="center">YES</td>
    <td class="center"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
$model = $query->skip($limit * ($page - 1))
            ->take($limit)
            ->get();

$result->totalItems = $this->model->count();
$result->items      = $model->all();
```

for `$model` you use `get()` and then when assigning to `$result->items` you use again `all()` method on it.

It should be here rather:

```
$result->items      = $model;
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the issue by remove the compact when I call the view. For example, it now stands as:

```
/**
 * List resources
 *
 * @return void
*/
public function index()
{ 
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $data = $this->model->getByPage($page, 10);
    $objects = Paginator::make($data->items, $data->totalItems, 10);
    $this->layout->content = View::make($this->namespace . '::admin.index')
        ->withObjects($objects);
}
```

Which means that I can now run the foreach as normal:

```
@foreach($objects as $user)
<tr class="">
    <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td class="center">Super Administrator</td>
    <td class="center">YES</td>
    <td class="center"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This seems to do the trick and all is well :)